# Is it possible to have personalized feed for Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Just like Google News, I want people visiting my Wordpress website to see different versions based on their personal preferences.

So, this is my website - www.spieltimes.com

When people visit it, I want a pop-up that asks them their favourite genres, consoles and games. Once selected, the website will change and curate content based on the person's preferences.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, and not all that difficult. You can store the users preferences as user meta data if you are requiring that they log in, or you can store this information in cookies as an easy way to track and access the data.

Comment: @JasonB could you help me with it?

Comment: I've created a room on chat.stackoverflow to continue the conversation. I will check in on the room and try to help you out if you like. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/188323/discussion-between-pingal-pratyush-and-jasonb?tab=general

Comment: I don't have 20 reputation to join the room. Can we talk here?

Comment: Can you create your form for collecting user preferences, then make a code pen of that and I can help you store the preferences